# How can I temporarily seal log home repairs to make it through the winter and prepare for a full refinish next spring?

Tags: wood, polyurethane, finish

My log home has some spots where finish is failing and some logs are rotting. My plan for August and September is to remove the rotten portions of logs and replace them with new wood. I’m experienced enough with wood to feel comfortable attacking this problem. I might be naive about this, but I’m going to go for it.

I am probably going to completely grind down the finish next summer, prep the home for new finish, and use a finish that will last 20 years with normal maintenance. That’s the plan. But the finish I will select will penetrate deep, and I don’t want to use it on the repairs that I make because I want to remove it in the spring when I grind and prep an entire wall.

What’s a good wood finish that I can use to get me through the winter? Something that will seal the wood through the winter, but which will come off when I need it to. I think this question is about penetration, I don’t want it to penetrate more than 1/4”, which is probably the amount of wood I’ll remove. I’m thinking of just some oil based spar urethane.

Answer (score 1):

I've used opaque stain (solid stain) on bare wood outdoors, and it worked well. I don't think it penetrated deeper than 1/16", but the wood was young. It's thinner than paint, and it doesn't form a thick film like paint does. Where I used it, rain beaded up on the surface after it cured, at least initially.

Opaque stain is quite thin and easy to apply. It can be sprayed on with a hand-held airless sprayer if desired, or applied with a brush.